# How to insert multi language data in SQL Server using N?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert, updates, multilingual

I know by using `N'...'` we can insert multi language data into SQL Server. But I don't know how to use it with parameters. Please help me..

My code is :

```
Alter proc proc_T_NewsAddUpdate
(  
    @Id bigint,  
    @Title nvarchar(500),
    @Description nvarchar(1000),  
    @image nvarchar(200),  
    @DateOfNews datetime,  
    @CreatedBy bigint,  
    @ModifiedBy bigint,  
    @IsVisible int,  
    @IsDeleted int  
)  
as  
    if exists(select 1 from T_LatestNews where ID=@Id)  
    begin  
        Update t_LatestNews 
        set Titlle = N@Title, 
            DesCription = N@Description,
            Image = N@image,
            dateOfnews = @DateOfNews,
            modifiedDate = GETDATE(),
            ModifiedBy = @ModifiedBy,
            Isvisible = @IsVisible,
            isdeleted = @IsDeleted 
         where 
            ID=@Id  

        select 1  
    end  
    else  
    begin  
        insert into t_latestnews (Titlle, Description, Image, dateofnews, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, isvisible, isdeleted) 
        values(@Title, @Description, @image, @DateOfNews, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), @CreatedBy, @ModifiedBy, @IsVisible, @IsDeleted)  

        select 1  
    end
```

Comment: let me paste my code.. that is not working.............

Comment: change the fields that you like to hold multi languages to nvarchar type. that should let you do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your stored proc to look like this:

```
Alter proc proc_T_NewsAddUpdate
(  
    @Id bigint,  
    @Title nvarchar(500),
    @Description nvarchar(1000),  
    @image nvarchar(200),  
    @DateOfNews datetime,  
    @CreatedBy bigint,  
    @ModifiedBy bigint,  
    @IsVisible int,  
    @IsDeleted int  
)  
as  
    if exists(select 1 from T_LatestNews where ID=@Id)  
    begin  
        Update t_LatestNews set Titlle=@Title,DesCription=@Description,Image=@image,dateOfnews=@DateOfNews,modifiedDate=GETDATE(),ModifiedBy=@ModifiedBy,Isvisible=@IsVisible,isdeleted=@IsDeleted where ID=@Id  
        select 1  
    end  
    else  
    begin  
        insert into t_latestnews (Titlle,Description,Image,dateofnews,CreatedDate,ModifiedDate,CreatedBy,ModifiedBy,isvisible,isdeleted) values(@Title,@Description,  
        @image,@DateOfNews,GETDATE(),GETDATE(),@CreatedBy,@ModifiedBy,@IsVisible,@IsDeleted)  
        select 1  
    end
```

Then call it like this:

```
exec proc_T_NewsAddUpdate
    @Id = 1, 
    @Title = N'Sample Title',
    @Description =  N'Sample Description',
    @image =  N'Sample Image',
    @DateOfNews = '1/1/2000',
    @CreatedBy = 1,
    @ModifiedBy = 1,
    @IsVisible = 1,
    @IsDeleted = 1
```

Comment: @dana VALUES ('english',N'हैलो दुनिया'english) in same column ...how to do that?? please suggest me

Comment: @DipGirase - You should be able to mix unicode characters from any language, for example `insert into MyTable(MyColumn) values (N'हैलो दुनिया english АВГДЄЅЗИѲ àèìòù')`. If you have a specific question, you may want to post a question. There are guidelines here regarding how to post a good one - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Feel free to tag me and I can take a look.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to insert data in table as NVARCHAR data type, like below.

–Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_LANG

(

LNAME VARCHAR(50),

LTXT NVARCHAR(100)

)
```

**–Insert “Hello World” in diffrent language**

```
INSERT INTO TBL_LANG

VALUES ('English',N'Hello World')

INSERT INTO TBL_LANG

VALUES ('Hindi',N'हैलो दुनिया')

INSERT INTO TBL_LANG

VALUES ('Chines',N'你好世界')

INSERT INTO TBL_LANG

VALUES ('Urdu',N'ہیلو دنیا')
```

–View Table data

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_LANG
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use nvarchar instead of varchar type.

Comment: what are the values you are trying to insert? and I think you dont need the N prefix that you are using now.

Comment: i want to insert Arabic values.. and english values

Comment: well, that should work then. get rid of the N prefix for the parameters. what is the result of the insert? is it an error or are you getting "????"